# Codepen: Project - CSS not working

Tags: html, css, path, codepen

Currently, I am trying to use Codepen Project's environment to build a website and later deploy it. I am using a template that I want to start building from. It has its own HTML pages as well as CSS and JS that is linked. However, when I am working in the project environment I cannot seem to get the CSS to apply to the html code (in other words, the live preview keeps showing naked HTML). I have tried uploading the files into the project's root, tried copying them in newly created css files, and tried using them as external sources (href to an external url in the head tag).

It is really to bad because I feel the Project environment can really offer a lot, though I just can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance, and take care!

LINK TO CODEPEN PROJECT:

https://codepen.io/Thumpertje/project/editor/DxxkqM/

```
<div class="code">
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like you are not linking properly your styles but with no code to check, can't help any more.

Comment: Can you share the link to your CodePen demo?

Comment: I added the project link above. Hopefully it can shed some light on the problem (it's a pretty big project so not sure what exact code I should show here).

Comment: When I check the preview link for the project (https://codepen.io/Thumpertje/project/full/DxxkqM/) it says that the project needs a index.html file. Try renaming your index-corporate-3.html to index.html; maybe Codepen Projects needs an index.html file to function properly? (I tried to fork the project and test this myself but I don't have a premium plan so it wouldn't let me.)